# Jest Mock a function's return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a simple function like this, I would like to mock the return value of authentication.getAccessToken() with a valid accessToken, I am having hard time doing this. Tried different ways but couldn't succeed, Can someone help me on this?

```
  import decodeJWT from "jwt-decode";      
  import authentication from "@kdpw/msal-b2c-react";

  export const testfunction = () => {
      const jwt = decodeJWT(authentication.getAccessToken());
      var current_time = Date.now() / 1000;
      var remaining_time = jwt.exp - current_time;
      return "testing done"
    }
```

Following is the unit test which I have been trying, As authentication.getAccessToken() doesn't get any value it is throwing InvalidToken error.

```
    import * as commonUtil from "../commonUtil";

    describe('test test function', () => {
       it("Mock", () => {        
          //The following runs but test fails due to null return
          const authentication = require("@kdpw/msal-b2c-react");
          authentication.getAccessToken = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false);
          expect(commonUtil.testfunction()).toBe(false)         
          }); 
       });
```

Error message

```
Comparing two different types of values. Expected boolean but received null.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `authentication` within your test.

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/module-function-mocking-with-jest-392r3) example. Open with editor to check out the unit tests.

In short, you need to do something like this.

```
test('test test function', () => {
    const resp = { data: '' };
    import authentication from "@kdpw/msal-b2c-react";
    authentication.getAccessToken = jest.fn().mockReturnValue("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbdjhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZR...");
    expect(commonUtil.testfunction()).toEqual("testing done")
});
```

Use `describe` to wrap test cases that uses mocked `authentication` so the mocked function will only stay local in that specific `describe` and everything outside it will use the real `authentication.getAccessToken()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the authenticaion that I was referring is from @kdpw/msal-b2c-react package. I am having hard time using your sample and get it working. I tried `const authentication = require("@kdpw/msal-b2c-react"); `  or `const authentication = require("@kdpw/msal-b2c-react").authentication;` but nothing  works. And the final received return is always null.

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli You don't have to follow my import method strictly. You can use your regular `import authentication from "@kdpw/msal-b2c-react";` instead. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @VenkateshMarepalli Now I understand why you're mocking `getAccessToken()`. Check out my updated CodeSandbox above.